# Salt ring around water heater

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, water-softener

I turned off my water heater while on vacation. I did not turn off my water softener. I returned home to find a salt ring outside the water softener overflow pan and what appears to be dried up water stain. It is a new water heater and providing hot water. What might the problem be?

Comment: Sounds like the water heater has nothing to do with it? Why do you think that it does?

Comment: There is a white salt residue ring at outermost edge of the dried watermark on  floor around water heater overflow pan.. In addition, in my online research, I read that when shutting of the water heater, one should also unplug the water softener. It does not appear that water was ever in the overflow pan. I am noticing discoloration on wall behind water heater and a drop of two of water on elbow of PVC pipe that brings water into the house. That elbow is very close to the wall. A similar problem occurred last year, and I thought it was a water heater leak and replaced the water heater!